# Correct use of Where in Query in YII2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I try to limit search result in Yii2 using Query class and where condition

```
$command=(new Query())          
         ->select('*')
         ->from('ct_ostatniNaklady')
         ->where('pid=:pid',[':pid' => 1])
         ->createCommand()->sql;

        var_dump($command);die;
```

However where command is not working properly. I get this result when I dump $command:

```
 string(48) "SELECT * FROM `ct_ostatniNaklady` WHERE pid=:pid"
```

I don`t know why is :pid string not replacing by 1.

Using diffent syntax has no effect

```
 ->where(['pid'=>'1'])
```

result is quite common:

```
  string(50) "SELECT * FROM `ct_ostatniNaklady` WHERE `pid`=:qp0"
```

What is correct way how to use where condition?

Comment: It is a placeholder, you are dumping the prepared statement. It'll be replaced on execution of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely normal, that is how PDO works. And you use where properly.

If you want to generate SQL query with every parameter bound to a variable value use:

```
...->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

PS. I hope you use it only for debugging and some special cases because usually there is no need to generate raw query like that.

Comment: I use it as input for SqlDataProvider

Comment: @user1041880 why don't you use `ActiveRecord` and `ActiveDataProvider` instead, or just create the SQL string by yourself. Otherwise, using `yii\db\Query` is overkill.